# Is it true $ N(P \cap M) = NP \cap NM = N(NC) \cap G = P \cap G = P $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of a solvable group $ G $, and assume that $ G = MC $, for some cyclic Subgroup $ C $. Let $ N $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Then $ N $ is an elementary abelian $ p $-group and $ M $ is a complement for N in G. If $ M_{G} = 1 $, then $ \vert C \vert $ is a power of $ p $. Let $ P = NC $, so $ P $ is $ p $-group. $ P \leq G $, since $ N \lhd G $ and $ C \leq G $. let $ S = P \cap M $. Now i want show $ S $ complements $ N $ in $ P $. We know $ N \cap S = N \cap (P \cap M) = 1 $. So sufficient show $ P = NS $. Is it true $ N(P \cap M) = NP \cap NM = N(NC) \cap G = P \cap G = P $?

And by Dedekind modular $ CS = C(P \cap M)= CM \cap P = G \cap P = P $ ?

Comment: Let $g \in P$. Then, since $G=NM$, $g=nm$ with $n \in N$, $m \in M$. Then $m=n^{-1}g \in P \cap M = S$, so $P=NS$.

Comment: @DerekHolt $ \vert N \vert = ? $ We have this lemma that if let $ P $ be a $ p $-group and let $ N $ be a nontrivial, elementary abelian normal subgroup of $ P $ which has a complement $ X $ in $ P $, if $ P = \langle y \rangle X $, then $ \vert N \vert = P $ if $ p > 2 $ and $ \vert N \vert  \leq 4 $ if $ p = 2 $.